# Whatsapp Crashing while sending video from Android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I am sending an Intent from Android code to whatsapp . Via Intent i am sending a Video . What different i am doing is adding the following param

```
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("number here")+"@s.whatsapp.net");
```

This helps me to directly jump into conversation without adding the contact .

But every time i reach the sharing screen of the contanct and press the send button to send the video , Whatsapp stucks/crashes .

Here is the full code :

```
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        sendIntent.setType("*/*");
        String downloadurl = "/storage/emulated/0/coke/4img.mp4";
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, downloadurl);

        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/coke/2img.mp4"));
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("number here")+"@s.whatsapp.net");//phone number without "+" prefix

        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I am sure the param line is causing it ,  but no idea why it hangs .

Any inputs ?

Comment: logcat please .

Comment: oops, that was a wrong video . But this peice of code will help many . its a direct way to send video on Whatsapp .